# How can I change the default terminal window size in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-terminal

I want to know how can I set the default terminal size in ubuntu 18.04. Previously in 16.04, there was an **Edit** option in menu bar but there isn't one in this new version. When I click on the options next to **New tab**, I can go into **Advanced** and then set the menu size to my desired one.

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 menu options]

[image: Window sizes under "Advanced"]

But when I close the terminal and reopen it, the settings aren't saved. Any help?

Comment: menu Preferences -> click on bottom left below Profiles probably called Unnamed ... here you choose your geometry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done through **Profiles** which is under in **Preferences**. You can create multiple profile and customize them.

Change **Initial terminal size** as shown in the image below. There are also many more customization choices there that you might be interested in. And even if you didn't find what you've been looking for, you always can use other terminal emulators like *terminator* instead of default *gnome-terminal*.

[image: Preferences in Gnome-Terminal]